# Where is the console (like Firefox Web Console) for debugging PHP?

Tags: php, debugging

I've just started to learning some coding. I've learn't some HTML, CSS, and JS so far. I'm currently working on a small PHP file, and I'm wondering where I go to debug PHP errors.

I'm uploading the small site (which is html5, css3, bootstrap and jQuery) to a HostGator server, so I have little to no control of that.

With JS I've been using the Firefox Console, and CSS I find the Inspector to be very good. Is there something similar for PHP?

My understanding is that PHP is all done on the server, but can I view errors in my PHP in my Browser? Or, do hosts (like HostGator) provide a console type interface, that I haven't been able to find?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

login to SSH, for how to read [here](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/how-do-i-get-and-use-ssh-access). write the following command in your SSH client/console

```
tail -f /path/to/error.log
```

it will give you live report but if you still not able to see the error, you need to add this lines to `php.ini`, or read [here](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/what-is-php-ini) for how to

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the beginning of your php code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language so you can't use the browser console like JavaScript. However, depending on what Editor your using, you can set up something like xDebug - https://xdebug.org/index.php, which will allow you to pause PHP during execution, see variable values, etc...

You can also use **var_dump()** http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php, to dump out values, etc...